# How use summery.value in tf version 2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, yolo

I try use tensorflow first time, recently.
And... I met many error message.

I solved just about error.
But, I  can't solved one error.

I use tensorflow version 2.0 because tf version 2.1 occurred DLL load failed error.
But yolo what I used was not tf version 2.0.
 I changed some yolo code to the with tf version 2.0.
But I can't change below code.

```
summary = tf.summary(value=[tf.summary.value(tag=tag, simple_value=value)])
```

How I can change this code to tf version 2.0 code?

Please Help me.

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to follow. What exactly is the issue you're facing? It seems like you're asking about multiple questions at once: DLL load, yolo v2 and tf summary. I'd recommend restructuring the question to ask 1 question and open separate questions for the rest

Comment: I solved DLL load problem with use tf version 2.0.
But yolo code is not use tf version 2.0.
So, I want code changed tf version 2.0 code.

Comment: summary = tf.summary(value=[tf.summary.value(tag=tag, simple_value=value)])

Comment: I want change above code to tf version 2.0.

Comment: 1) Create a `writer`, then use that in a `with-clause` and write. 2) [tf2.0 summary docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/summary) 3) What exactly is the problem you're facing. What error do you get when running the code you've shown?

Comment: AttributeError: module 'tensorboard.summary._tf.summary' has no attribute 'Value'

Comment: Above is error message. So, I change 'Summary.Value' code to tf version 2.0 code.